# Test class methods using Pytest

Tags: python, function, oop, testing, pytest

I am taking a programming course now, CSE 111 programming with functions, and my last assignment is to find an interesting code and write some test functions, to test the correct working of the code. This is the code:

```
#Imported modules
import sys
import wave, contextlib, math, time
import speech_recognition as sr
from moviepy.editor import AudioFileClip
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    """Main window GUI."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialisation function."""
        self.mp4_file_name = ""
        self.output_file = ""
        self.audio_file = "speech.wav"
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        """Define visual components and positions."""
        # Main window
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(653, 836)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 20, 161, 41))
        # Selected video file label
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.selected_video_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.selected_video_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 20, 371, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.selected_video_label.setFont(font)
        self.selected_video_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.selected_video_label.setText("")
        self.selected_video_label.setObjectName("selected_video_label")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 161, 41))
        # Transcribed text box
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.transcribed_text = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.transcribed_text.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 320, 381, 431))
        self.transcribed_text.setObjectName("transcribed_text")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 280, 161, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.transcribe_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.transcribe_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 150, 221, 81))
        # Transcribe button
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.transcribe_button.setFont(font)
        self.transcribe_button.setObjectName("transcribe_button")
        self.transcribe_button.clicked.connect(self.process_and_transcribe_audio)
        # progeress bar
        self.progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progress_bar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 250, 381, 23))
        self.progress_bar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progress_bar.setObjectName("progress_bar")
        self.message_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.message_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 760, 651, 21))
        # Message label (for errors and warnings)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(8)
        self.message_label.setFont(font)
        self.message_label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
        self.message_label.setText("")
        self.message_label.setObjectName("message_label")
        self.output_file_name = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.output_file_name.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 90, 371, 41))
        # Output file name
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.output_file_name.setFont(font)
        self.output_file_name.setObjectName("output_file_name")
        # Menubar options
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 653, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        self.menuAbout = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuAbout.setObjectName("menuAbout")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.setObjectName("actionOpen_mp4_video_recording")
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.triggered.connect(self.open_audio_file)
        self.actionAbout_vid2text = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout_vid2text.setObjectName("actionAbout_vid2text")
        self.actionAbout_vid2text.triggered.connect(self.show_about)
        self.actionNew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionNew.setObjectName("actionNew")
        self.actionNew.triggered.connect(self.new_project)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNew)
        self.menuAbout.addAction(self.actionAbout_vid2text)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuAbout.menuAction())
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        """Translate UI method."""
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Selected video file:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Output file name:"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Transcribed text:"))
        self.transcribe_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Transcribe"))
        self.output_file_name.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "interview1.txt"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.menuAbout.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
        self.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Open mp4 video recording"))
        self.actionAbout_vid2text.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About video to speech"))
        self.actionNew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "New"))
    def open_audio_file(self):
        """Open the audio (*.mp4) file."""
        file_name = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        if file_name[0][-3:] == "mp4":
            self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(True)
            self.mp4_file_name = file_name[0]
            self.selected_video_label.setText(file_name[0])
        else:
            self.message_label.setText("Please select an *.mp4 file")
    def convert_mp4_to_wav(self):
        """Convert the mp4 video file into an audio file."""
        self.message_label.setText("Converting mp4 to audio (*.wav)...")
        self.convert_thread = convertVideoToAudioThread(self.mp4_file_name, self.audio_file)
        self.convert_thread.finished.connect(self.finished_converting)
        self.convert_thread.start()
    def get_audio_duration(self, audio_file):
        """Determine the length of the audio file."""
        with contextlib.closing(wave.open(audio_file,'r')) as f:
            frames = f.getnframes()
            rate = f.getframerate()
            duration = frames / float(rate)
            return duration
    def transcribe_audio(self, audio_file):
        """Transcribe the audio file."""
        total_duration = self.get_audio_duration(audio_file) / 10
        total_duration = math.ceil(total_duration)
        self.td = total_duration
        if len(self.output_file_name.toPlainText()) > 0:
            self.output_file = self.output_file_name.toPlainText()
        else:
            self.output_file = "my_speech_file.txt"
        # Use thread to process in the background and avoid freezing the GUI
        self.thread = transcriptionThread(total_duration, audio_file, self.output_file)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.finished_transcribing)
        self.thread.change_value.connect(self.set_progress_value)
        self.thread.start()
    def finished_converting(self):
        """Reset message text when conversion is finished."""
        self.message_label.setText("Transcribing file...")
        self.transcribe_audio(self.audio_file)
    def finished_transcribing(self):
        """This run when transcription finished to tidy up UI."""
        self.progress_bar.setValue(100)
        self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(True)
        self.message_label.setText("")
        self.update_text_output()
    def set_progress_value(self, val):
        """Update progress bar value."""
        increment = int(math.floor(100*(float(val)/self.td)))
        self.progress_bar.setValue(increment)
    def process_and_transcribe_audio(self):
        """Process the audio into a textual transcription."""
        self.transcribe_button.setEnabled(False)
        self.message_label.setText("Converting mp4 to audio (*.wav)...")
        self.convert_mp4_to_wav()
    def update_text_output(self):
        """Update the text box with the transcribed file."""
        f = open(self.output_file, "r")
        self.transcribed_text.setText(f.read())
        f.close()
    def new_project(self):
        """Clear existing fields of data."""
        self.message_label.setText("")
        self.transcribed_text.setText("")
        self.selected_video_label.setText("")
        self.output_file_name.document().setPlainText("")
        self.progress_bar.setValue(0)
    def show_about(self):
        """Show about message box."""
        msg = QMessageBox()
        msg.setWindowTitle("About video to Speech")
        msg.setText("Nelson Petro - CSE 111")
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msg.exec_()

class convertVideoToAudioThread(QThread):
    """Thread to convert mp4 video file to wav file."""
    def __init__(self, mp4_file_name, audio_file):
        """Initialization function."""
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.mp4_file_name = mp4_file_name
        self.audio_file = audio_file
    def __del__(self):
        """Destructor."""
        self.wait()
    def run(self):
        """Run video conversion task."""
        audio_clip = AudioFileClip(self.mp4_file_name)
        audio_clip.write_audiofile(self.audio_file)
        
class transcriptionThread(QThread):
    """Thread to transcribe file from audio to text."""
    change_value = pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, total_duration, audio_file, output_file):
        """Initialization function."""
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.total_duration = total_duration
        self.audio_file = audio_file
        self.output_file = output_file
    def __del__(self):
        """Destructor."""
        self.wait()
    def run(self):
        """Run transcription, audio to text."""
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        for i in range(0, self.total_duration):
            try:
                with sr.AudioFile(self.audio_file) as source:
                    audio = r.record(source, offset=i*10, duration=10)
                    f = open(self.output_file, "a")
                    f.write(r.recognize_google(audio))
                    f.write(" ")
                self.change_value.emit(i)
            except:
                print("Unknown word detected...")
                continue
            f.close()
            
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I have written these two test functions. The first one to test the default values of the `MainWindow` constructor and the second one to test the correct functionality of the
`open_audio_file()` function (using the directions provided in a previous question). I am not pretty familiar with OOP, so I would really appreciate if you can help me getting the second function working correct.

These are the two test functions:

```
def test_MainWindowConstructor():
  ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  assert ui.mp4_file_name == ""
  assert ui.output_file == ""
  assert ui.audio_file == "speech.wav"

def test_that_providing_a_raw_file_is_rejected():
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
  ui = Ui_MainWindow()
  ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
  ui.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.triggered
  QFileDialog.getOpenFileName = "video.raw"  
  ui.open_audio_file
  assert ui.message_label.text == "Please select an *.mp4 file"
```

Thank you so much before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
  ui.actionOpen_mp4_video_recording.triggered
  ...  
  ui.open_audio_file
```

As written, that doesn't make sense.
You probably want to invoke a function,
rather than evaluate an expression for
side effects and then discard it.
There's a big difference between `fn` and `fn()` --
the latter actually calls the function.

You *are* successfully verifying that the `triggered`
attribute exists, and that can be helpful in a unit test.
To verify, try some typo, such as "fliggered",
and note the AttributeError that elicits.

Similarly you are verifying the `open_audio_file`
attribute exists. That's a simpler situation so
it is probably less useful for a unit test to do that.
Better to call the function, and verify it behaves
as intended.

---

Try running your tests in this way:

```
$ pytest --cov --cov-report=term-missing
```

That will help you to notice that there's two
kinds of audio files you should test:
with & without an ".mp4" suffix.

---

Note that the target code sometimes mentions
a function without calling it, without
tacking on `()`. What's going on there?
We name that situation a "[callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)#Python)".
That is, the target code's API accepts
a *pointer* (ok, a *reference*) to a function.
It remembers the function, and subsequently *calls*
it at the appropriate time, after some UI event
has happened.
That syntax was likely confusing you -- it explains
the absence of `()` in the target code.

---

Academic integrity

You are clearly learning some things
about unit tests in this assignment,
and have commendable curiosity.
Be sure to include a reference to
this SO question when you hand in your work.
Most schools are happy with use of external
resources as long as you cite them.